# Qual o mais correto "vai ser" ou "será"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, português-europeu, tempo-verbal, frases

Ontem ouvi um político dizer na tv:

> vai ser na próxima semana...

Qual o mais correto "vai ser" ou "será"?

Comment: Fechei a pergunta como duplicada, se achar que a resposta da duplicada não responde à pergunta, por favor edite e acrescente as dúvidas que tem.